# Maven project, choose default Tomcat context / path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a **big maven project** containing **several modules**. Some of the modules, after build produce **war** which are deployed to Tomcat. Deploy is done **without** the maven plugin. Currently I use Intellj 15, and manually run Tomcat 7 with chosen projects to be deployed.

The problem is that by default, **all** projects are deployed to "/", which obviously does not work. In other case, when I manually specify a path for each project, it can lead to different configurations on different computers.

Is there any parameter that could be set in `pom.xml` or `web.xml` or any other file, that would specify the default path (context) for the applications to be deployed at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the maven tomcat plugin?
[maven-tomcat7 plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html)

Seems like the deploy goal with the path parameter is exactly what you need.

Comment: is there any other way to set it, not using the maven-tomcat plugin?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is - is there a reason why you don't want to use the tomcat7 plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If every project is a standalone web application (is a different war) you can configure tomcat to deploy the different projects on different contexts.

See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html as a starting point.

In your web.xml you can also specify url-filters for the different filters or servlets, regarding which url paths they should 'listen on'. You can use this to deploy different filters or servlets within one webapplication (war) on different url paths *within the same context*.

See for starters https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Servlets_and_URL_Paths

Comment: Tomcat configuration is not the way either as it would require to add tomcat path to repository to force uniform configuration among the team.